# Struts2 Action Invoke not giving error message

Tags: jsp, struts2

I've below entries in struts.xml

```
    <action name="download" method="download" class="com.pqr.myaction">
        <result name="error" type="redirectAction">callme</result>
    </action>

    <action name="callme" class="com.pqr.myaction">
        <result name="imhere" type="tiles">imhere.tiles</result>        
    </action>
```

imhere.tiles corresponds to imhere.jsp in tiles & shows "download" link.

When I click download, I'm constructing the URL to donwload the package from & if that is null, I'm returning error & also setting class variable this.errMsg = "ERROR" & then displaying it in imhere.jsp
as shown below:

```
       <s:if test="errMsg != null"> 
          <div id="normalErrMsg"><p><s:property value="errMsg" escape="false" /></p></div>
        </s:if>

     <a href="/download">
        <s:property value="getText('DOWNLOAD')" escape="false" />
     </a>
```

But somehow, the control does not go to the above if condition at all.

Can any one tell me what is worng this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: use chain result instead of redirectAction, this will do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `redirectAction` is just that, a redirect. Request attributes and parameters are lost, because it's a new request, new action instance, etc.

You can either forward, maintaining the URL in the address bar and staying in the same action, use the `"scope"` interceptor to temporarily store messages/data, or store the messages in the session yourself and remove them on entering `myaction`.

In this case I'm not sure I'd bother redirecting, though.

Comment: I'm pretty new to struts2, I'll appreciate if you can provide an example how to use it....

Comment: @Mike Use what? There's at *least* the three options I listed--why do you need to redirect at all?

Comment: Hi Dave, I meant can u provide an example of scope interceptor? I'm new to struts2

Comment: @Mike There are config examples in the [interceptor's docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/scope-interceptor.html). Again, why do you want to redirect at all?